# How to properly bind a shared property of a sub-usercontrol dependency property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, viewmodel

I've 4 different collections. Currently I display thoses 4 collections, but I can only have one element selected at the time.

The view where I display the 4 collection:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.yyy.vvv.Menu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx.yyy.vvv.Menu"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="450">
    <Grid  Name="RootContainer">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MenuViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CollectionControl Collection="{Binding}" SelectedElement="{Binding Path=DataContext.GlobalSelectedElement,ElementName=RootContainer, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is bound to a ViewModel:

```
public class MenuViewModel : SomeBaseViewModelThatHandleTheNotify
{
    public IMyElement GlobalSelectedElement
    {
        get => GetValue<IMyElement>();
        set => SetValue(value); //I NEVER COME HERE!!!)
    }
    public SomeCollectionContainer Collection
    {
        get => GetValue<SomeCollectionContainer>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

My sub control, has a dependency property, which is changed when the internal ViewModel of the UserControl is changed.

```
    public IMyElement SelectedElement
    {
        get { return (IMyElement)GetValue(SelectedElementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedElementProperty, value);/*HERE I COME!*/ }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedElementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedElement", typeof(IMyElement), typeof(CollectionControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedElementChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedElementChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        //Retrieve the sub control ViewModel and set the property
        SubControlViewModel subControlViewModel = (SubControlViewModel)((CollectionControl)dependencyObject).RootContainer.DataContext;
        subControlViewModel.SelectedElement = (IMyElement)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
    }

    //In the constructor, I register to PropertyChanged of the ViewModel, and I set the SelectedElement when it change.
```

So, basically, I come in the SetValue of the dependency property of the UserControl, but I never come in the `GlobalSelectedElement` property of my main ViewModel.

What did I miss?

**EDIT**
I tried to directly use two-way binding between my ViewModel and the Dependency Property, doesn't work either:

In my sub control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.yyy.vvv.CollectionControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx.yyy.vvv.Menu"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Name="RootContainer" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:CollectionControlViewModel/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <Label Content="{Binding Collection.Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection.Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CollectionControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I feel that my UserControl DependencyProperty is bound from 2 sides

I've tried to make a small diagram to show my classes.
So my `CollectionControl.SelectedElement` are correctly set, but the `MenuViewModel.SelectedItem` are not.

[image]

Comment: Do not access a view model from the PropertyChangedCallback of a dependency property. Use a TwoWay Binding instead.

Comment: How do you bind SelectedElement to GlobalSelectedElement?

Comment: @Clemens It's between the ViewModel of the UserControl and the Dependencies property of the UserControl, not between the View and the ViewModel, I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @mm8 I'm sorry, for some reason, StackOverflow was not displaying the XAML, it should be more clear now.

Comment: There should be nothing like a "ViewModel of the UserControl". It should only have dependency properties that are bound to an "external" view model. An own, "private" view model should be replaced by simple logic in the control's code behind. The "internal" Bindings in the control's XAML should use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` to bind to the dependency properties of the control.

Comment: @Clemens We UnitTest all the logic of our UserControls, so we need to have internal ViewModels(but I've tried your approach(see my edit). Also, we have properties that we want to be bindable from inside our UserControl but not from the external part.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, SelectedSlot is the `actual` code, I changed "Slot" by element here because I thought it was more clear to work with items than slot. Slot are a business domain model.

Comment: @J4N: Does this work? `<local:CollectionControl Collection="{Binding}" SelectedElement="{Binding Path=DataContext.GlobalSelectedElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: @mm8 It does seems to work! I'm doing some additionals tests, but for now it looks promising! How is this different from the `SelectedElement="{Binding Path=DataContext.GlobalSelectedElement,ElementName=RootContainer, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` I used?

Comment: @J4N: The `CollectionControl` and the `Grid` belong to different namecopes.

Comment: @mm8 What is a namescope? I think it would helpful to provide some details why the previous approach was not working. Because there was no Binding errors.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind to the `DataContext` of the parent `ItemsControl` using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<local:CollectionControl Collection="{Binding}" 
                         SelectedElement="{Binding Path=DataContext.GlobalSelectedElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Obviously using an `ElementName` doesn't work. This is because of [namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes). The `CollectionControl` element in the `ItemTemplate` is not in the same namescope as "RootContainer".

Comment: Great! Any idea why VisualStudio was happy with it?

Comment: Visual Studio? No, but it's only the runtime behaviour that matters.

Comment: I agree, but in the runtime, I've no Binding error(in the output window)

Comment: So? Obviously you should use a RelativeSource as I have suggested in my answer. Please accept it if your issue has been solved and then ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Obvious? Is this a joke? Obvious is not when VS AND the runtime accepts your binding without outputing any error?

If you reference something that WPF is not able to find on your DataContext, it should(and generally does) output it in the logs.